# How Activity Layout Selection works in Android

Tags: android, layout

I have creating a layout for Samsung tab 2 but getting confuse about the layout selection process.

As layout-sw600dp means that it will be used when the smallest side is equal or greater that 600dp.

And in Samsung tab 2 in portrait height is 976dp and width is 600dp but in landscape mode width is 1024dp and height is 552dp.

And when i am using tab in landscape mode then layout-sw600dp is calling.  I am unable to understand why is it happening when the smallest side is 552dp.

Please provide you comment on this.